# Speed up read in of netcdf data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, netcdf

I have a matlab script that reads in multiple netcdf files using ncread(), and it does this ~7220 times. It reads in this many times to avoid overloading the memory. An example of this is below:

```
for l = 1:380

% some code here

   for r = 1:19
    
       % code here
    
       % Import
       T = ncread(sprintf(fn1,str,hx,A),'THETA',[1 1 1 valID],...
           [Inf Inf nlvs 19],[1 1 1 1]);
       eta = ncread(sprintf(fn2,str,hx,A),'ETAN',[1 1 1 valID],...
           [Inf Inf 1 19],[1 1 1 1]);
       w = ncread(sprintf(fn3,str,hx,A),'WVEL',[1 1 1 valID],...
           [Inf Inf nlvs 19],[1 1 1 1]);

       % more code here

   end
   
   % more code here
end
```

When I run the analysis using a fairly coarse grid resolution 200x200x53 (nx x ny x nz) it takes approximately 11 hours on a single node. This is fine. But I am trying to analyse a finer resolution model, so 1000x1000x75. This means the run time is approximately 25 times longer, so takes ~11 days. Is there a way that I can multithread/parallelise the read in of the netcdf data so that I can run the script using more nodes. Or is there a way to speed up the read in using a different matlab function.

I have tried scouring the web for some hints at how to speed this up, but I cannot find a solution. Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Generally file I/O is a bottleneck. More threads does not make your hard drive spin faster, and its the hard drive who tends to be the bottleneck. Surely reading from 1 file instead of thousands its faster, but that may not be an option for you.

Comment: If your loop iterations are independent of each other, maybe you could use something simple like [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). Otherwise, python-dask is fast growing as the tool of choice for big memory data manipulation spread over a scalable cluster. Presumably matlab has some sort of equivalent.